# Enabling the recursive traversing mode in command prompt based search as per user's choice

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe, search

I have following script to search for files of specific file types(PHP, TXT, HTML etc.), which asks for user's choice about:
1) Whether to do a recursive search ?
2) Which type of files to be listed out ?

But due to unknown reason, even if I give positive answer ("y") for the resursive search question, it doesn't search recursively and exits after the current directory search is finished.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set /p inSubFolders="You want to search in sub-folders too ? : "
set /p searchTerm="What type of files are you looking for ? : "

echo %searchTerm%
echo %inSubFolders%

:findInDir
if %inSubFolders%=="y" (
    dir *.%searchTerm% /s /b /p | findstr /e .%searchTerm%
) else (
    dir *.%searchTerm% /b /p | findstr /e .%searchTerm%
)
pause
```

Can anyone find out what could be the reason for this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What could be the reason for this problem?

```
if %inSubFolders%=="y" (
```

The above is broken as it compares `y` with `"y"`

It should be:

```
if "%inSubFolders%"=="y" (
```

---

#### How could I have pagination?

Pipe the output to [`more`](https://ss64.com/nt/more.html) as follows:

```
dir *.%searchTerm% /s /b /p | findstr /e .%searchTerm% | more
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) - Conditionally perform a command.
- [more](https://ss64.com/nt/more.html) - Display output one screen at a time. MORE can be used to run any executable command (or batch file) and pause the screen output one screen at a time.

Comment: Thanks for that, but how could I have pagination, like when pressed enter it should load next page results and so on ?

Comment: @VickyDev That's really a new question, but I'm feeling generous today. See updated answer.